# Start and End node in Critical Path Calculation

Tags: critical-path

I have to calculate the critical path for a project, where activity A and C can start in parallel. Please see the image below

[image]

Since I had two activities that could start in parallel (A and C), I also used the dummy start node. Similarly, since my project had 2 nodes at the end (B and D), I added the dummy end node.  Please tell me if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, adding start and finish milestones to the network is correct.  (Calling them "dummy nodes" is unconventional, as that term is usually reserved for activity-on-arrow diagrams.)
2. You might want to double-check your calculations.  Conventional terminology starts the project on Day 1, not Day 0.  In addition, your start and finish days are not consistent with the durations shown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please refer to the inconsistency (other than start day being 1)? Isn't the Critical Path Start->C->D->End?

Comment: Yes, the CP is as you've stated.  The problem is in the meaning of the dates.  For example, you've shown activity A with an early start on (the morning of) Day 0 and an early finish on (the evening of) Day 2.  That's 3 days (0,1,2), which doesn't match the 2-day duration shown. Overall, you've got the project starting on (the morning of) Day 0 and finishing on (the evening of) Day 9 - i.e. 10 days, while it's longest path is clearly 9 days (3+6).  The morning/evening distinction is important, and you've left out the required +1/-1 adjustments in your math.